# Searching for actors JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, innerhtml

I'm making a function to find the all movies made by the actor i search for, the movies are in a js file like so:

```js
var filmlist = [ 
  {"Title":"Killer's Kiss", "Actors":"Frank Silvera, Jamie Smith, Irene Kane, Jerry Jarrett"}
];

var a = document.getElementById("film");

function findActors() {
  var x = document.getElementById("actor").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("actorfilm");

  a.innerHTML = "Movies with this actor: " 
  for (var i=0; i<filmlist.length; i++) {
    if (x.indexOf(filmlist[i].Actors) !== -1) {
      y.innerHTML = (filmlist[i].Title + "<br/>")
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="2" cols="50" id="actor" placeholder="write actor name, and press the button"></textarea>
<button onclick="findActor()">ActorButton</button>

<p id="film"></p>
<p id="actorfilm"></p>
```

For some reason it wont show the actors, but it shows the first a.innerhtml
Im very new to javascript so any help is appreciated.

Comment: what did you entered in the textarea?

Comment: you have written `findActor` in the html and `findActors` in the js

Comment: See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zgvobu9/) for working example using your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, just that your `if` condition needs to be reversed.

```
if (filmlist[i].Actors.indexOf(x) )
```

You were *checking the superset of actors within the value you have input*, rather than doing it the other way round.

You can make it more precise by doing

```
var filteredFilms = filmlist.filter( s => s.Actors.indexOf(x) != -1 );
var output = filteredFilms.map( s => s.Title ).join( "<br/>" );
```

**Demo**

```js
var filmlist = [{
  "Title": "Killer's Kiss",
  "Actors": "Frank Silvera, Jamie Smith, Irene Kane, Jerry Jarrett"
}];

var a = document.getElementById("film");

function findActors() {

  var x = document.getElementById("actor").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("actorfilm");
  a.innerHTML = "Movies with this actor: "
  var filteredFilms = filmlist.filter(s => s.Actors.indexOf(x) != -1);
  y.innerHTML = filteredFilms.map(s => s.Title).join("<br/>");

}
```

```html
<!-- find actor function -->
<textarea rows="2" cols="50" id="actor" placeholder="write 
actor name, and press the button">Frank Silvera</textarea>

<button onclick="findActors()">ActorButton</button>


<p id="film"></p>

<p id="actorfilm"></p>
```

Comment: still cant make it print it out by reversing index of :/

Comment: @GustavBangNielsen Check the demo.

Comment: I changed the for and if loop to your solution and did the indexOf reverse, still no results..

Answer (score 0):

You are currently overwriting `y.innerHTML` with the last movie title. To append, to the innerHTML use:

`y.innerHTML += (filmlist[i].Title + "<br/>")`

There is an issue with your indexOf, mentioned in another answer and can be fixed with

`if (filmlist[i].Actors.indexOf(x)) {`

Lastly, your HTML is incorrectly referencing the js function and should instead be:

`<button onclick="findActors()">ActorButton</button>`

Comment: While you are correct, this is not the issue OP is facing.

Comment: As @Adriani6 mentioned, the initial problem is your if statement comparing the indexOf on a string, not the array. Check my answer now, or gurcinder372's answer

Comment: yeah i changed both, still no result

Comment: Check the comments on your original post, appears to be a typo with `findActor()` in your HTML, when your JS function is `findActors()`

Comment: ah sorry it's a typo, well spotted!